# Reading logs from kibana through an API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

So I'm looking for a way to read the kibana logs for my app through a REST API. Searching online didn't lead to what I wanted. I have an app called `glass` and the logs for it look like this:

[image]

I added a filter specifying `application` `is` `glass` and it yields these logs collected in the last 15 minutes.

Is there a REST API which I can use to get those logs from Postman for example?

I've also played with the Dev Console but I'm not sure I understand how to use it.

I've went through these docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/api.html but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top-right of the Discover window, you have a button labeled "Inspect". Clicking on it will reveal the query that Kibana is sending to Elasticsearch.

You can copy it and paste it into the Dev Tools console in order to play with it. You can also send it directly to Elasticsearch (the same way Kibana does it), using the Elasticsearch [`_search` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search.html). So you don't want to send your query through Kibana (which is just another ES client), but directly to your Elasticsearch server.

Comment: Yeah I figured kibana is just the visualization tool. I found the request. Thanks!

Comment: Do you by chance know how I can convert that request to send it from Postman instead of the Dev tools console?

Comment: You don't need to convert anything, you can copy/paste it into Postman, use the ES server `_search` endpoint URL, add `Content-Type: application: json` (+ Basic auth is you have any setup) and you're good to go

Comment: @Val how to find out API endpoint URI either of kibana/elasticsearch to use it from command line or python
My enterprise admin just gave me kibana URL which I can access console etc, but ultimately I want to write program over that data